# Как объденить все байты массива в целое число

Tags: c++, byte

Пишу редактор сохранений для NFS:MW. Пока что работаю над проверкой на валидность файла, но на этом моменте уже возникли проблемы. У меня есть массив Magic_Bytes[4];, а так же строка save.read(Magic_Bytes, 4); записывающая магические байты в массив.
Мне как то нужно перевести массив из 4х байт в целую переменную int в порядке little-endian, что бы сравнить ее с магическим числом.

Comment: Приведите пример массива.

Comment: Если порядок байтов совпадает, то можно указатель на нужный байт привести к указателю на int и разыменовать, иначе можно завести union, в который занести в нужном порядке байты, а прочитать int

Comment: @MBo Ой, чувствую, получите сейчас от ревнителей стандарта...

Comment: @Harry А почему, если little-endian указан? Или дело в другом?

Comment: @MBo Кажется, strict aliasing или что-то в этом роде (я это даже запомнить никак не могу, если честно, не то чтоб всерьез прочувствовать... просто для себя вывел, что не хочешь, чтоб тебя мордой в UB тыкали — никому не показывай приведение указателей к другому типу. Насколько я помню, можно только к `char*`, что ли...) Как и `union` использовать для преобразования - только что внес, то и бери, но не другой тип. При том, что реально — работает, похоже, везде и всегда, но формально UB. Впрочем, тут пусть истинные гуру рассказывают. А правильно байтики из массива умножать и складывать в `int`...

Comment: @Harry Ох, беда. Так это и все reinterpret_cast побоку пойдут... Ну да ладно, при беглом просмотре - тема сложная, определения плохо читабельны. В общем - иметь в виду, но внутрь не зарываться.

Comment: @MBo Вот-вот... Я примерно так и поступаю, в результате игнорируя подобные вопросы :), но в программе при случае... Ой, молчу, молчу!!! :) А тут еще — массив байт (которые беззнаковые) и знаковый `int`. Т.е. встает вопрос представления знаковых чисел в компьютере. Плюс вопрос о количестве битов в байте и `int`'е. Плюс о совпадении endian в массиве и числе... Блин, я бы на месте TC читал сразу в `int` и не мучился. Или сравнивал через `memcmp` :)

Comment: @DimoNULL Определение `save.read` покажите

Comment: В плюсах вот прям весь функционал прям из коробки... библиотека <bitset> - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset твори с битами что хочешь, дроби на байты, соберай инты, дроби на массивы, сэты темплейты.